# Add Data Ids in the Doc2Vec model

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, vectorization, doc2vec

Please, can you help me ? I've trained a Doc2Vec model to transform a "keywords" input into vectors. I've made predictions with a TensorFlow model, using these vectors. Is there a way to keep the unique IDs in the Doc2Vec model to fit their predictions in the TensorFlow model?

Here is my code for the generation and training of the Doc2Vec Model :

```
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec
import gensim
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument

def label_sentences(corpus, label_type):
    labeled = []
    for i, v in enumerate(corpus):
        label = label_type + '_' + str(i)
        labeled.append(doc2vec.TaggedDocument(str(v.split()).split(';'), [label]))
    return labeled

X_data = label_sentences(test.keywords, 'Data')
model_dbow = Doc2Vec(dm=0, vector_size=300, negative=5, min_count=1, alpha=0.065, min_alpha=0.065)
model_dbow.build_vocab([x for x in tqdm(X_data)])
%time
for epoch in range(30):
    model_dbow.train(utils.shuffle([x for x in tqdm(X_data)]), total_examples=len(X_data), epochs=1)
    model_dbow.alpha -= 0.002
    model_dbow.min_alpha = model_dbow.alpha
```

Here is the code of the vector that I put in the TensorFlow model :

```
all_data_vectors_dbow_test = get_vectors(model_dbow, len(X_data), 300, 'Data')
test = all_data_vectors_dbow_test
```

And here is the code of the predictions :

```
test_pred = sess.run(activation_OP, feed_dict={X: test})
```

Comment: Separate from the matter of displaying the same IDs through your TF operations: in `Doc2Vec`, you shouldn't be calling `train()` multiple times, or trying to manage `alpha`/`min_alpha` yourself. (And, `alpha=0.065` is an odd starting value I've never seen before.) See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53768789/130288 for one of many places where the problem with this approach is explained.

Comment: Thank you very much @gozomo, I've created the Doc2Vec model with no parameters alpha and min_alpha. I've trained it once. And it worked.