# Gensim doc2vec file stream training worse performance

Tags: nlp, gensim, doc2vec

Recently I switched to gensim 3.6 and the main reason was the optimized training process, which streams the training data directly from file, thus avoiding the GIL performance penalties.

This is how I used to trin my doc2vec:

```
training_iterations = 20
d2v = Doc2Vec(vector_size=200, workers=cpu_count(), alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.00025, dm=0)
d2v.build_vocab(corpus)

for epoch in range(training_iterations):
    d2v.train(corpus, total_examples=d2v.corpus_count, epochs=d2v.iter)
    d2v.alpha -= 0.0002
    d2v.min_alpha = d2v.alpha
```

And it is classifying documents quite well, only draw back is that when it is trained CPUs are utilized at 70%

So the new way:

```
corpus_fname = "spped.data"
save_as_line_sentence(corpus, corpus_fname)

# Choose num of cores that you want to use (let's use all, models scale linearly now!)
num_cores = cpu_count()

# Train models using all cores
d2v_model = Doc2Vec(corpus_file=corpus_fname, workers=num_cores, dm=0, vector_size=200, epochs=50)
```

**Now all CPUs are utilized at 100%**

but the model is performing very poorly.
According to the documentation, I should not use the train method also, I should use only epoch count and not iterations, also the min_aplpha and aplha values should not be touched.

The configuration of both Doc2Vec looks the same to me so is there an issue with my new set up or configuration, or there is something wrong with the new version of gensim?

P.S I am using the same corpus in both cases, also I tried epoch count = 100, also with smaller numbers like 5-20, but I had no luck

**EDIT**: First model was doing 20 iterations 5 epoch each, second was doing 50 epoch, so having the second model make 100 epochs made it perform even better, since I was no longer managing the alpha by myself.

About the second issue that popped up: when providing file with line documents, the doc ids were not always corresponding to the lines, I didn't manage to figure out what could be causing this, it seems to work fine for small corpus, If I find out what I am doing wrong I will update this answer.

The final configuration for corpus of size 4GB looks like this

```
    d2v = Doc2Vec(vector_size=200, workers=cpu_count(), alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.00025, dm=0)
    d2v.build_vocab(corpus)
    d2v.train(corpus, total_examples=d2v.corpus_count, epochs=100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most users should not be calling `train()` more than once in their own loop, where they try to manage the `alpha` & iterations themselves. It is too easy to do it wrong.

Specifically, your code where you call `train()` in a loop is doing it wrong. Whatever online source or tutorial you modeled this code on, you should stop consulting, as it's misleading or outdated. (The notebooks bundled with gensim are better examples on which to base any code.)

Even more specifically: your looping code is actually doing 100 passes over the data, 20 of your outer loops, then the default `d2v.iter` 5 times each call to `train()`. And your first `train()` call is smoothly decaying the effective `alpha` from 0.025 to 0.00025, a 100x reduction. But then your next `train()` call uses a fixed `alpha` of 0.0248 for 5 passes. Then 0.0246, etc, until your last loop does 5 passes at `alpha=0.0212` – not even 80% of the starting value. That is, the lowest alpha will have been reached early in your training.

Call the two options exactly the same except for the way the `corpus_file` is specified, instead of an iterable corpus.

You should get similar results from both corpus forms. (If you had a reproducible test case where the same corpus gets very different-quality results, and there wasn't some other error, that could be worth reporting to `gensim` as a bug.)

If the results for both aren't as good as when you were managing `train()` and `alpha` wrongly, it would likely be because you aren't doing a comparable amount of total training.

Comment: Turns out in the case where corpus_file is provided the doc ids are not line ids, my logic relies on that and I thought it was not classifying them correctly. Is there a way to define the id of each document to avoid this?

Comment: In fact, when using `corpus_file`, the only doc-tags are the line numbers – equivalent to if you were using the `TaggedLineDocument` class, which just numbers each line from 0. There is currently no option to supply your own tags if using `corpus_file` mode.